# Ask user for IPv4 address and verify if valid or not. If not, then ask for IP again until valid

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I am able to prompt the user for their IP address and check whether it is valid or not, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get this program to ask the user for another IP address if the one entered is invalid. Any help would be great!

```
import ipaddress 

def validate_ip_address(address):
    while True:
        try:
            ip = ipaddress.ip_address(address)
            print("IP address {} is valid.".format(address, ip))
        except ValueError:
            print("IP address {} is not valid".format(address))
            continue
        else:
            break
ip = input("Enter an ip: ")
validate_ip_address(ip)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to write an if else statement for an IP address

Comment: There's nothing there that requires an `if` `else` statement. You basically just need to wrap this in a very simple `while` loop. What about the answers in that linked post do you not understand?

Comment: @RandomDavis I tried using a while True but my except just keeps looping on the output.

Comment: @Nate You need to change the value of `address` in the loop. One way is to move the `input()` call inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

With the `while` loop in place, you are still only requesting input from the user once. You need to request the input inside the `while` loop to allow the user to try again.